# html5 geolocation accuracy gives me often value 0

Tags: html, geolocation

I'm using on my website the HTML5 geolocation API to get the position of a user with High Accuracy set to true. See below Code.

It works fine except that I receive very often an accuracy of 0. Why?

I checked the docu online and several posts here, all are explaining something +- 20 is normal but couldn't find anything where a 0 can come from.

0 is definitely wrong as the position was often 2km away from where I was standing.

Used devices, Various Android Tablets with SIM Card on Android 8 and 10.

Any idea how I can improve this or what 0 means?

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
    if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation, positionError, {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 10000,
    maximumAge: 0
} );
}else{
        alert('Location sharing is not supported by your browser. Please update it accordingly or contact Oliver.');
        $('#location').html('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
}
});
```